# Button Class's object is not adding to a layout container object (HBox, VBox, etc). Is there no default constructor of HBox or VBox to accept Button?

Tags: button, layout, containers

I am using eclipse & I have tried to add the Button class object to a layout container in java but it says that there is no constructor to accept Button's object change it to the Node.

Code

```
Label myLabel = new Label("Click here to see notification");
            Button myButton = new Button("Click Me");
            HBox hBox = new HBox(10,myLabel,myButton);  // I get error in this line
```

Error:
The constructor HBox(Button, int, int) is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

java's [documents](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html) instrocts you to write:

```
 HBox hbox = new HBox(10);
 hbox.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Click here to see notification"), new Button("Click Me"));
```